# Raising an exception using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, error-handling

I have been trying to get a program utilizing concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor to raise an exception when needed. For some unknown reason, when I run my code the program does not raise an exception. Here is my code (referencing other classes I've built):

```
import pickle
import concurrent.futures
from BoxesSimulation import SimulationResults, QuenchedGridTrailBiasSimulation
from BoxAnalysis import BoxAnalysis, DistributionResults
import misc


def sim_func(tilescale):
    number_of_iterations = 75
    loadloc = 'middle'
    pickle_file_name = 'Pickle Files/ExperimentalBoxDistribution' + loadloc + '.pickle'
    cube_densities = [100, 150, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 400]
    bias_values = ('hooke', 0.8, 10, 0.3)
    for cube_density in cube_densities:
        for seed in misc.seed_from_txt_files(cube_density):
            for iteration in range(1, number_of_iterations+1):
                print('scale = ' + str(tilescale) + ',seed = ' + seed + ',iter = '
                      + str(iteration))

                sim = QuenchedGridTrailBiasSimulation(pickle_file_name, bias_values,
                                                      seed=int(seed), num_stones=cube_density,
                                                      tile_scale=tilescale)

                load_path, load_trajectory_length, load_time, where_out = sim.run_simulation()
                try:
                    ResultsObject.append(SimulationResults(load_path, load_trajectory_length,
                                                           load_time, where_out, tilescale,
                                                           cube_density, seed=int(seed)))
                except NameError as e:
                    if e.args[0][5:16] == 'ResultsObject':
                        ResultsObject = SimulationResults(load_path, load_trajectory_length,
                                                          load_time, where_out, tilescale,
                                                          cube_density, seed=int(seed))
                    else:
                        raise
                except AttributeError:
                    ResultsObject = SimulationResults(load_path, load_trajectory_length,
                                                      load_time, where_out, tilescale,
                                                      cube_density, seed=int(seed))
    results_pickle_file_name = 'Pickle ' \
                               'Files/QuenchedMidBiasSimulationResults_Simulated_Cubes_Scale_' \
                               + str(tilescale) + '_iterations_' + str(number_of_iterations) \
                               + '.pickle'
    with open(results_pickle_file_name, 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump([ResultsObject, tilescale, cube_densities, number_of_iterations,
                     bias_values], handle,
                    protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)


def main_func():
    scale_list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 15]
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        executor.map(sim_func, scale_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_func()
```

This piece of code should raise a NameError in the Try-Except Block appending ResultsObject (the indices checking for the string ResultsObject in the NameError are wrong on purpose (side thought - maybe I should use regular expressions here... never really used it but it seems like a good spot to start)). However, When the program reaches the `raise` command nothing happens. All the workers continue to work until they all reached the same error and then the program ends without raising the error and also without completing the intended work, as all of the processes actually ended in an (unraised) error.

To test this, I tried to modulate the example code provided in the ProcessPoolExecutor to raise an exception:

```
import concurrent.futures 
import math

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]


def is_prime(n):
    while True:
        try:
            a.append(3)
            break
        except NameError:
            if 0:
                a = [2]
            else:
                raise

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    print(str(sqrt_n))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True


def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('{!s} is prime: {!r}'.format(number, prime))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works perfectly and returns the wanted UnboundLocalVariable Error.
I would like to understand where the difference stems from,and how I can make my code also raise an error as expected. 
Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Are the scripts you present really [mcve]? You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: hmm. The thing is, I don't know what causes the problem. The second script is quite straightforward. The first is definitely not complete nor minimal as it is dependent on other custom classes I built, but I wanted to show it as is since the problem arises in this part of the script (the raise statement) and I have no simple way of removing stuff from it one-by-one, nor do I know which part of it causes the problem.

Comment: You may consider that the deluge of answers you're getting is an indication of how easy it is to decipher your input as it is given now.

Comment: When you eliminate the unnecessary parts from your original script, to create a [MCVE], you'd end up in one of two situations: 1) the problem disappears, which means that it stemmed from the parts you eliminated, or 2) the [MCVE] still produces the problems, in which case you may be helped by the SO community.

Comment: The sarcastic tone is completely unnecessary. I'm well aware of what would happen if I "eliminate the unnecessary parts" from my original script. Problem is - it is much easier said than done. I don't expect people to delve into my code and try to understand everything in it. I was just trying to see if anybody ran into a similar problem and maybe it is something generic and common with ProcessPoolExecutor, that I'm unaware of. Apparently it is not.

Comment: You may be a victim of a reverse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poe%27s_law, namely, you found sarcasm where none was intended. Ah well, yet again - the inadequacy of non-verbal communication raises its ugly head.